# Is playing free lotteries haram?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, gambling

Is it haram for Muslim to play lottery without paying any pine and win money? I mean just pick numbers for free without paying money and win money.

Comment: "paying any pine"? While I grok the meaning from context, I can't tell if that's a colloquialism I'm unfamiliar with, or just a typo.

Comment: Do you mean for fun/games? I haven't heard of a lottery that lets you win lots of money without some sort of payment.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not putting out any of your wealth and you have no chance of losing it, then it's not haraam and you can play it.

Something being called "lottery" doesn't necessarily make it haraam.  We have to see what's involved.